# How to choose specific content i want to pass to the mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I have a @mixin call skewed in SASS.

```css
@mixin skewed {
  position: relative;
   &::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
    @content;
  }
  &::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
    @content;
  }
}
```

From above, you can see that there has @content inside "before" and "after".
The below is the "footer" class, how to pass the content to "before" but not "after".

```css
footer {
  padding: 2em 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: $color-shade;
  margin-top: 3.5em;
  @include skewed {
    background-color: red;
    top: -25px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just exclude `@content` in `&::after`?

Comment: Is that possible to open two properties in mixin for other class to extend ?

Comment: footer { &::after {display: none}}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default variable and a conditional.

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e510844566b7226641a7858a92633648)

```
@mixin skewed($doesAfterHaveContent: false) {
  position: relative;
   &::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
    @content;
  }
  &::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);

    @if ($doesAfterHaveContent) { @content; }
  }
}

.footer {
  @include skewed {
    color: red;
  }
}

.hey {
  @include skewed(true) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```